# Haskell parse error on input `=' on a simple line

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to learn Haskell and I got this error.
`` parse error on input `=' ``
Here is my code:

```
nAnd1 :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
nAnd x y = if (x==False && y == False) || x/=y then True else False

nAnd2 :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
nAnd x y | if ((x == False && y == False) || x/=y) = True
         | otherwise = False
```

The place where the error takes place is at the "=" before True in nAnd2. Any solution?

Comment: remove `if` after `|`

Comment: but why after definition of type in `nAnd1` and `nAnd2` you write `nAnd`?

Comment: `if ... then True else False` is just a long way of writing `...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to drop the `if` was already given. I suppose the exercise was meant differently. The `nAnd` means "not and", i.e.

```
nAnd a b = not (a && b)
```

but you have `nAnd x y = (not x && not y) || x /= y`. That is very strange and I suspect an X-Y-Problem here. Did you get the definition of nand from a truth table?

```
  a  |  b  | a `nAnd` b
-----+-----+----------
False|False|   True
False|True |   True
True |False|   True
True |True |   False
```

Then take the time to rewrite the truth table as

```
  a  |  b  | a `nAnd` b
-----+-----+----------
True |True |   False
  *  |  *  |   True
```

and use Pattern Matching:

```
nAnd :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
nAnd True True = False
nAnd _    _    = True
```

Answer (score 2):

The guards (`|`) act as if clauses, it does not make sense to write `if` for these:

```
nAnd :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
nAnd x y | (x == False && y == False) || x /= y = True
         | otherwise = False
```

It furthermore however is odd to return `True` or `False` based on a condition, you can rewrite this to:

```
nAnd :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
nAnd x y = (not x && not y) || x /= y
```

or we can negate the values and use `(||)`:

```
import Data.Function(on)

nAnd :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
nAnd = on (||) not
```